# Laravel: migrate if connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.5

My project is a multi-database project. Some migration files I have to run on all databases and some on one or two database. My question about: How to investigate the connection name?

So if my migration file is like

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MigrationFile extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){

        if($database == 'myseconddatabase') {

          //code

        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

and I give the command `php artisan migrate --database=myfirstdatabase`

How to give the value 'myfirstdatabase' to the `$database` variable?

Comment: Use protected $database = 'myseconddatabase'; Before the up() function.

Comment: @PedroFaria99 Thank you. And `protected $database = ['myseconddatabase', 'mythirddatabase']` is valid if I want to run it for two connections?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i wouldn't try that, that way anytime u require a database connection u would need to specify the array key.So just dont botter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections are on config/database.php

whatever you gonna do, you can handle it using the DB::connection,
a get option demonstrates it.

```
$pvArray = DB::connection('myconn_mysql')->table('products')->select('id')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I know, but the question is about if I run the `php artisan migrate --database=xy` command, how can I reach the xy from the migration file?